# Outputting the correct balance from payments in each row

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

This is probably simple. But I’m at a standstill. I am using Coldfusion 2021 on a Windows PC. I am trying to Output data that has the sum of payments made by a couple of individuals.  This sum of payments is subtracted from a goal number of $425. When one of our members make a payment of say $5 dollars one day, then $20 another day, the output would total their payments to date of $25. But I want that payment to date to subtract from the static number of $425 within the output which should be a balance of $400 and so on. But I’m getting some wacky results in my balance column whenever I cfoutput my query. Anyone have any ideas that may point me in the right direction? Below is the code that I used and Below that are two images, one shows the incorrect balance column and the other one shows my desired balance column.

[![Below is the code that I used and Below that are two images, one shows the incorrect balance column and the other one shows my desired balance column.]
[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) --> "Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem.", kindly paste your code as **TEXT**.

Comment: If you only need to subtract a static number from a query generated number, why not do it when outputting the results instead of asking the db engine to do it? Also, I realize this is test code but make sure you use <cfqueryparam> when adding coldfusion variables to queries.

Comment: I think using SUM() is why your results are weird.  It doesn't sound like you're intending to add records to each other which is what SUM does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a hard-coded activityCost and activityDeposit (or obtained from elsewhere), there's no need to send them to the database at all.  Just get the SUM() of the payments, then in your single-row-per-group output, do the math there, like:

#activityCost - activityDeposit - expense.balance#

And expense query's "balance" column, you might rename it after removing the unnecessary values to just "payments" since that's really what you're grabbing from the database.

Comment: thank you for your help. your answer was so simple i could not see it right in front of me.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are more complicated than necessary.  This will get your data:

```
select fname, lname, sum(buspayamount) as AmountPaid
from name join bustrip on name.foiid = bustrip.busfoiid
where whatever, maybe a date range
group by fname, lname
```

This will display it:

```
<table>
<tr> table headers go here
</tr>
<cfoutput query = "nameofquery">
<tr>
<td> #fname# #lname#</td>
<td>$#AmountPaid#</td>
<td>$425-#AmountPaid#</td>
closing tags
```